# python : extract submatrices from indices

Tags: python, indexing

I have a matrix and a list of indices for both dimensions.

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
idx = [1,3,4]
idy = [2,5,7]
```

What is the similar notation from Matlab doing A(idx,idy) in Python?

Comment: You have `list` of `lists`, not matrix. You need `numpy.array(A)`, but both sets of indices exceed both axis.

Comment: There is no easy way to acess columns. You'd be able to access the row `i` in the matrix as `row=A[i]`. Indexing columns would require e.g. Python generator expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my exmple:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

idx = [0, 1]
idy = [1, 2]

a = [[A[ix][iy] for iy in idy] for ix in idx]
print(a)
```

From:

```
[
   [1, 2, 3], 
   [4, 5, 6], 
   [7, 8, 9]
]
```

I am obtaining the submatrix according to my indexes `idx` and `idy`:

```
[
    [2, 3], 
    [5, 6]
]
```

Please keep in mind that in python indexing start from `0` so giving the fact that here we have a 3x3 matrix the smallest index is `0` and the biggest is `2` for each row and column.

Is this what you are looking for? Please let me know.